# Select from array with given substring value

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I have an array which looks like this:

```
arr = ["value1", "value2 spot", "value3", "value4", "value5 spot", "value6"]
```

and I would like to select and return an array with all values which have the `spot` substring.

```
arr.select{|v| v == regex_here}
```

how would I be able to do this?

Comment: How about: `.*\bspot\b.*`

Comment: `a, b = arr.partition {|s| s[/spot/]}` then `a` returns true values, `b` returns false values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `grep` method

```
 arr.grep(/spot/)
  => ["value2 spot", "value5 spot"]
```

Other request you made

```
arr.group_by { |item| item.match(/spot/) != nil }
 => {false=>["value1", "value3", "value4", "value6"], true=>["value2 spot", "value5 spot"]}
```

Comment: thanks, this works great! Can you also assist to get all values which *don't* have the substring spot seperately.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Try `partition` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
arr.select{ |i| i[/spot/] }
 => ["value2 spot", "value5 spot"]
```

Comment: “should” is a wrong word here—the most proper solution would be to use `grep`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Okay cool